# Opening QGIS project says layers not available

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-processing, geopackage

I created a QGIS project with four geopackage layers for an uni project. I made sure to include all four geopackage layers in the same folder as the QGIS project and then zipped it to send it to my friends. But once they try to open it QGIS shows a chart with my four layers and asks if they want to keep these unavailable layers.

I recreated the layers, checked the path etc. it just won't work.

I'm new to QGIS.

Comment: The solution by @MrXsquared should work. Still, a workaround would be to manuelly paste the path to the files in the dialog saying that layers are missing.

Comment: You could use the QPackage plugin to create a folder with the project and files which avoids path issues.  Once sent there are easy fixes, including using the change Data Source plugin (which has lots of uses) or following any of the suggestions in the QGIS documentation for handling broken file paths: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/project_files.html

Answer (score 5):

Go to `Project -> Properties -> General` and make sure `Save paths` is set to `relative`:

[image]